# WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR results in deleted folders and dysfunctional apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, mysql, operating-systems

Basically I was confronted two times with WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR which resulted once in missing folders in particular spaces in my Desktop(can't recall to have deleted them in a random fashion myself) and after the second one I got a MySQL error "Root element is missing".

Is this certainly a case of damaged memory? And if so, should I buy a new SSD for my laptop?

Comment: It certainly sounds like you should replace your storage device

Comment: First of all, run `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` to check if component store is corrupted, if so, run `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` to repair component store. Then run `sfc /scannow` to repair system files. You are dealing with a hardware failure. Then run `chkdsk C: /f /r /x` to scan for any file system errors and bad sectors. And finally run `mdsched.exe` to check for any RAM failures. If any hard failure is found, you have to replace your hardware.